# measure time taken for API call

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to get the time taken for an API call.

i have a web application with angularJS front end and nodejs back end which has end to end connection.

route in back-end

```
app.get('/api/eventUploadRead', function(req, res) {
         filesReadUploads.find(function(err, events) {                
              if (err)
                  res.send(err);
              res.json(events);
          });
      });
```

service in front end which call the api

```
getUploadRead : function() {
        return $http.get('/api/eventUploadRead');
    },
```

controller

```
getEventsOfUploadedFile();
 $scope.events;
    function getEventsOfUploadedFile()
    {
        Event.getUploadRead()
        .success(function(event){
        $scope.events=event;
        })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load event data: ';
        });
    }
```

what i want to do exactly is get the time spent until the data passed to the controller from the API call.t
the reason to do this is,i want to measure the time change with the decrease of data load.i want to decrease data load and measure the time taken to load accordingly.

can anyone help me this?if not clear please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`console.time()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)/[`console.timeEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd) to time the request:

```
function getEventsOfUploadedFile() {
  console.time('getUploadRead');
  Event.getUploadRead()
    .success(function(event) {
      $scope.events = event;
    })
    .error(function(error) {
      $scope.status = "Unable to load event data: ";
    })
    .finally(function() {
      console.timeEnd('getUploadRead');
    });
}
```

Comment: @ robertklep  i should get the difference of two console outputs,, right??

Comment: @MSKP no, you'd get _one_ console output telling you how much time it took between the `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` calls. So `console.time()` starts the timer, `console.timeEnd()` ends it and also logs the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a timer before and after service call to calculate the time taken.

```
  var start = new Date().getTime();
    getEventsOfUploadedFile();
     $scope.events;
        function getEventsOfUploadedFile()
        {
            Event.getUploadRead()
            .success(function(event){
              var end = new Date().getTime(); 
            $scope.events=event;
            })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load event data: ';
            });
        }
    total_time = end - start;
```

You can also use the the chrome developer tools to analyse the time of service calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use performance.now(). This [link](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/144/measuring-the-performance-of-a-function-with-javascript-using-browser-tools-or-creating-your-own-benchmark) has some comparisons between console.time and performance.now.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the above by @Vivz, I use the [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) functions to measure durations (ms).

```
/* start time ‘test’ */
console.time('test');

/* stop time ‘test’ */
console.timeEnd('test');

/* stop time output ms */
test: 8254.471ms
```